# Como puedo hacer para guardar una relación entre 2 tablas en una tabla pivote

Tags: laravel

Buenas tardes desarrolladores me pueden ayudar por favor con esta duda para relacionar uno o varios ingredientes a un producto.

La idea es que un producto puede tener varios ingredientes asociados y que a la hora de asociar los ingredientes a un producto necesito que guarde en la tabla pivote ingredientes_productos

No se que error tendré o que me hace falta para que me ejecute la relación, en la migración productos quité la relación entre producto e ingredientes TABLA PRODUCTOS tiene los siguientes campos: NOMBRE, VALOR, CATEGOARIA_ID, ESTADO_ID

TABLA INGREDIENTES tiene los siguientes campos: NOMBRE, VALOR, CATEGORIA_ID.ESTADO_ID

Tabla pivote

````
{
    Schema::create('ingredientes_productos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->bigInteger('ingrediente_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->index();
        $table->foreign('ingrediente_id')->references('id')->on('ingredientes');

        $table->bigInteger('producto_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->index();
        $table->foreign('producto_id')->references('id')->on('productos');

        $table->integer('cantidad');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}```

en la tabla pivote llamo al id de productos y ingredientes

Modelo productos

    ```<?php
        
        namespace App\Models;
        
        use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
        use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
        
        class Producto extends Model
        {
            use HasFactory;
        
            protected $fillable = ['nombre', 'valor', 'estado', 'categoria_producto'];
        
            public function categoria()
            { //$libro->categoria->nombre
                return $this->belongsTo(Categoria_Producto::class); //Pertenece a una categoría.
            }
        
            public function relaciones()
            {
                return $this->belongsToMany(Ingredientes::class, 'ingredientes_productos', 'ingrediente_id')
                    ->withPivot('producto_id', 'ingrediente_id')
                    ->withTimestamps();
            }
        }```

Modulo Ingredientes

    ```<?php
    
    namespace App\Models;
    
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
    
    class Ingredientes extends Model
    {
        use HasFactory;
        protected $table = 'Ingredientes';
        protected $fillable = ['Nombre', 'Valor', 'Cantidad', 'categoria_Ingredientes'];
    
        public function productos()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany(Producto::class, 'ingredientes_productos')
                ->withPivot('producto_id', 'ingrediente_id')
                ->withTimestamps();
        }
    }```

Controller para guardar un producto y los ingredientes que le asocie

    ```<?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Producto;
    
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use App\Models\Producto;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
    
    class ProductoController extends Controller
    {
        public function store(Request $request)
        {
            
    $producto = Validator::make($request->all(), [
               
     'nombre' => 'required|string|unique:productos,nombre',
            
    ]);
           
     if ($producto->fails()) {
               
     return response()->json(["errors" => $producto->getMessageBag()], 
    
    422);
           
     }
           
     $productos = Producto::create($request->all());
    
           
     $productos->productosIn()->sync('categoria_id');
    
            
    return response()->json(['message' => 'Creado con exito'], 200);
        
    }
    
    }```
````

Comment: no tienes nada llamado productosIn, sino productos

Comment: si eso me di cuenta tenia que quitar el productosin y poner porductos y en el controller debia poner
 $productos->productos()->attach($request->AQUI DEBIA PONER EL ID CON EL QUE SE RELACIONA);

Answer (score 0):

SOLUCION

MODEL INGREDIENTE

`````
 ```public function producto()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Producto::class);
}````
`````

MODEL PRODUCTO

`````
```public function Ingrediente()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Ingredientes::class)->withTimestamps();
    }````
`````

CONTROLLER

````
```public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $productos = Producto::create($request->all());
        $productos->Ingrediente()->attach($request->ingrediente_id);

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Creado con exito'], 200);
    }```
````

Comment: Para mejores practicas te recomiendo que uses nombres en ingles y nombres de las funciones en  lowerCamelCase, solo es recomendacion

Comment: @Dohko19 dale gracias